# What kind of tool will loosen this nut holding a chainwheel on a one piece crank?

Tags: chainring

Can someone tell me how to remove this nut that is holding the chainwheel in place on this one piece crank? In the picture below, the red arrows are pointing to three slots in the nut that a tool would fit into to remove the nut.

Is there a name for a too like that? I looked on the park tools web site but I didn't see anything.

Is there a way to loosen it without having to buy a specialized tool?

Thanks in advance,

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm looking for a translation for the tool based on these German wikipedia pages:
https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hakenschl%C3%BCssel
https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nutmutter

Comment: Maybe Parktool HCW-5 will fit?

Comment: A *Hakenschlüssel* is a *hook spanner* or sometimes *C spanner* (so spanner rather than key but a similar word)

Comment: Yeah, in the US it's usually some variation of "spanner" (which is distinguished from "wrench").

Comment: Some locknuts for bottom brackets used that kind of wrench. They were also in use for locknuts on old-style motorcycle headsets. So you might be lucky inquiring at a motorbike dealer/workshop.

Answer (score 8):

Such a tool may be called hook spanner.

The nut is holding the inner race of the bottom bracket bearing.

A web search with "bottom bracket" and "hook spanner" produces a couple of hits. (For instance, the tool mentioned by Klaster in the comments.) You may use a vernier caliper to determine the dimensions of your nut and find the right tool for you.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to clamp the lower crank in a vice and use a hammer and brass drift into the three notches.

Downside, heavy blows are likely to distort the metal, so use more but gentler taps.  A smaller hammer helps with control.

This is a one-piece crank, so they're not exactly known for having fine tolerances.

Comment: I'ev done this successfully recently (with a BB lockring on a beater bike).  The thing I'd be wary of with this approach is doing it back up again - the hook spanner is much more controlled

Answer (score 0):

They come in various sizes.
I think you need something like this:
[hook spanner](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001DNT2W0)